# How to tell Intel Pin to profile only a specific function

Tags: x86, x86-64, profiling, intel, intel-pin

I want to profile a specific function in a large piece of code using Intel Pin. I have compiled my code with -O3, so I cannot access the debug symbols. I'm compiling my code using the following command:
`gcc -O3 -march=native -pedantic -o bin/baseline_main baseline_main/main.c`.

I have written a pin tool to track branches and count them. The tool looks at the instructions and if an instruction is a branch instruction, it adds a call to increment a counter. At the end of the profiling period, the tools simply prints out the branch instruction count.

If I run this tools with a simple C code with no branches, I still get a branch count of 25950. The code which gave me this number is shown below. I suppose that this count is not zero due to the code being executed by my OS's loader. I want to know if I can somehow tell the pin tool to only instrument the main function and to ignore the rest of the execution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>                                                                                                                                           

int main()
{
        volatile bool x = false;
        volatile int y = 0;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `-O3 -g`.  Including symbol names is not mutually exclusive with optimization.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have two follow up questions. 1: Wouldn't adding -g disable certain optimizations? 2. How can I detect labels in my pin tool?

Comment: No effect on code-gen.  Did you look at the linked duplicates (scroll up to the top of the page)?  The one about `-O2` and `-g` covers that in a comment on the top answer.  As for symbols in PIN, the other duplicate cover that, I think.  I'm not very familiar with PIN tools, but those look like they're basically doing the same thing, or would be easy to adapt.